# adding a static html page to Django project

Tags: django, templates, static

I'm new to Django and web coding.

I'm following Bucky tuts: Django Tutorial for Beginners - 28 - Creating a Base Template.

I thought of viewing the template page when requested ( PATH/templates/music/base.html ) but I don't know how to do it.

I searched to find that I could put something like this in urls to make it work  :

```
path('base', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'music/templates/music': 'base.html'}),
```

but didn't work.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this code that is shown in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf) ?

```
from django.urls import path, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# django 2.0
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
]

# django 1.11 and prior
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
]
```

Comment: Thanks man , worked (y)
I got lost a bit in the docs and didn't extract the info well from it :) :)